# Button weirdly not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a web app but I've encountered a problem.

Most of the app's interfaces consist of lots of buttons and I've encountered a queer phenomenon whereby I can't click some of the buttons (there's no clicking animation and  the onclick() doesn't run).

I've noticed that where there are multiple buttons stacked on top of each other, only the last line of buttons is clickable.

I have created a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div style="padding-top: 20%;" id="div1">
        <button>
            Button 1
        </button><br />
        <button>
            Button 2
        </button>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "initial";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Further observations/notes:

When you go to select an element from the developer menu, you can't select the malfunctioning buttons.

I'm using Firefox. I get a similar issue with my app in Chrome but the buttons which misbehave are different to the ones that break in Firefox.

I'm trying to create a single-page web app by hiding and showing various `<div>` elements (different screens) by setting `display: none;` and `display: initial;` respectively. That's the reason for the `<script>`. Is there a better way I should be doing this?

Comment: It's because of the `initial` style being added. Is there a reason for wanting that?

Comment: yes, @ComputerLocus is right. This behavior is because of the style.

Comment: It is because of display `inline` (`initial` will default to `inline` for the display property) in combination with the top padding.

Comment: @MarkBaijens Maybe make that an answer since you seem to have a good explanation of the issue?

Comment: It's weird, I copied the code and ran, its working.

Comment: @ComputerLocus It's more an observation than an answer. Maybe someone can post an answer why this is happening. I know to little about css and the specification to do that.

Comment: @MarkBaijens I think it may be useful to know what they are trying to do using the `initial` so that maybe alternative solutions could be suggested that alleviate the issue.

Comment: The code is working for me, with or without the inline css

Comment: @MonikaMangal, have you checked it in the chrome.

Comment: yes I tried in chrome. @AlokMali

Comment: This might help: http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/

Comment: @KoshVery initial set display to inline and not to default browser

Comment: @KoshVery It does not set to the browser/element default value but the specification default value which is inline for the display property.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, @MarkBaijens, thanks, I understood the spec incorrectly %)). Default for `display` prop is `inline` for sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`display: initial;` is equivalent to `display: inline;` in your case.

The `padding-top` is then applied to each line of content, making the second line cover the first line. It is easier to see if you add a background to the containing div.

```css
#div1 {
 padding-top: 15px;
 display: initial;
 background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
 <button>
  Button 1
 </button>
 <br>
 <button>
  Button 2
 </button>
</div>
```

Comment: it's no really related to box decoration but to the fact that the height of linebox is only defined by line-height and everything else (padding,border,margin, etc) will simply *overflow*

Comment: I thought the padding was applied to the whole `<div>` element. How do I make it work that way?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, my bad, I will remove that part of the answer.

Comment: @IssaChanzi any display other than `inline` (`initial`)

Comment: @IssaChanzi there are a few ways, the simplest being to use `display: inline-block;` instead.

Answer (score -4):

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div style="padding-top: 20%;">
        <button>
            Button 1
        </button><br />
        <button>
            Button 2
        </button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```